# Getting Label Text of CheckBox from a CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, .net, list, checkedlistbox

I currently have a CheckedListBox with several boxes.  I want to be able to test every Checkbox in the list to see if it's checked, and if it is, add it's text value (CheckBox.Text) to a List of strings.

Here is what I have:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < multiTaskChecks.Items.Count; i++ )
{
    if ( multiTaskChecks.GetItemChecked(i) )
    {
        checkedMultiTasks.Add(multiTaskChecks.GetItemText(i));
    }
}
```

Using this, `GetItemText` is returning 0, 1, 2, 3, etc instead of the text values that I'm after.  I have also tried `CheckedListBox.Text.IndexOf(i)`, `CheckedListBox.Text.ToList()`, each without any luck.

I just cannot get the label text of one of these CheckBoxes from the CheckedListBox.  Any help with this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you should be able to loop through the checked items only like so

```
foreach (var item in multiTaskChecks.CheckedItems)
{
}
```

then depending on the type of the `item`, get whatever property you want from it.  Sounds like it is just a Text or you just want the string, so

```
foreach (var item in multiTaskChecks.CheckedItems)
{
    checkedMultiTasks.Add(item.ToString());
}
```

or I prefer

```
checkedMultiTasks.AddRange(multiTaskChecks.CheckedItems.
    OfType<object>().Select(‌​i => i.ToString()));
```

Comment: I don't want to edit your answer, or add this to mine, but this is what you'd need to do:  'checkedMultiTasks.AddRange(multiTaskChecks.CheckedItems.OfType<object>().Select(i => i.ToString()));'

Comment: @Jay thanks for the heads-up - I didn't actually try it, obviously enough.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < multiTaskChecks.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (multiTaskChecks.GetItemChecked(i))
    {
        checkedMultiTasks.Add(multiTaskChecks.GetItemText(multiTaskChecks.Items[i]));
    }
}
```

[ListControl.GetItemText Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext.aspx)

**NOTE** There's a caution regarding `DisplayMember` for this method:

`If the DisplayMember property is not specified, the value returned by GetItemText is the value of the item's ToString method. Otherwise, the method returns the string value of the member specified in the DisplayMember property for the object specified in the item parameter.`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var checkedMultiTasks = new List<string>();
foreach(var item in multiTaskChecks.CheckedItems) {
    checkedMultiTasks.Add(item.ToString());
}
```